# Firestore Android reconnect time after internet loss is too long (~10 mins)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to handle internet loss/recover in android application, written with firebase, firestore, react-native & react-native-firebase.

I realized, that calling "firestore.enableNetwork" right after internet appears (I detect state of network using RN's NetInfo api) took too long - up to 10 mins. But if I restart application, it connects faster.

After debugging for a while, I realized that problem is in native firebase android sdk - it waiting for ~10 minutes before timeout lost socket connection and attempt to reconnect.

Is there any way to force reconnect? I tried to use "enableNetwork" / "disableNetwork", but this does not help.

Comment: I am observing the same behavior in a project written in xamarin (xamarin's language is C#, but it "simply" wraps the java methods in c# methods, so basically it is the same code). Did you find any solution to this issue?